# How to use POST requests in MS Graph Batches

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I am struggling to get my batch request to work and it always hangs up on the line related to my post request CreateLink(). I am struggling to understand how to do POST request in batches. MS documentation indicates POST request are handled differently in batches than GET request. My code is as follows:

```
    public async Task<OneDriveFile> BulkFileImportAsync(string DriveID, string Path)
    {
        OneDriveFile oneDriveFile = new OneDriveFile();

        try
        {

            var fileInfoRequest = _graphServiceClient.Me.Drives[DriveID].Root
                        .ItemWithPath(Path)
                        .Request();
            var fileEditRequest = _graphServiceClient.Me.Drives[DriveID].Root
                        .ItemWithPath(Path)
                        .CreateLink("edit", "users", null, null, null, true)
                        .Request();
            var fileViewRequest = _graphServiceClient.Me.Drives[DriveID].Root
                        .ItemWithPath(Path)
                        .CreateLink("view", "users", null, null, null, true)
                        .Request();
            var fileThumbnailRequest = _graphServiceClient.Me.Drives[DriveID].Root
                        .ItemWithPath(Path).Thumbnails
                        .Request();

            // Build the batch
            var batchRequestContent = new BatchRequestContent();

            var fileInfoRequestId = batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(fileInfoRequest);
            var fileEditRequestId = batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(fileEditRequest);
            var fileViewRequestId = batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(fileViewRequest);
            var fileThumbnailRequestId = batchRequestContent.AddBatchRequestStep(fileThumbnailRequest);

            var returnedResponse = await _graphServiceClient.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batchRequestContent);

            var fileInfo = await returnedResponse
                       .GetResponseByIdAsync<DriveItem>(fileInfoRequestId);
            var fileEdit = await returnedResponse
                       .GetResponseByIdAsync<Permission>(fileEditRequestId);
            var fileView = await returnedResponse
                       .GetResponseByIdAsync<Permission>(fileViewRequestId);
            var fileThumbnail = await returnedResponse
                        .GetResponseByIdAsync<IDriveItemThumbnailsCollectionPage>(fileThumbnailRequestId);

            oneDriveFile.Path = Path;
            oneDriveFile.WebURL = fileInfo.WebUrl;
            oneDriveFile.EditURL = fileEdit.AdditionalData["webUrl"].ToString();
            oneDriveFile.ViewURL = fileEdit.AdditionalData["webUrl"].ToString();
            oneDriveFile.ThumbnailURL = fileThumbnail.CurrentPage[0].Large.Url;

        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error doing batch update: {ex.ToString()}");
        }

        return oneDriveFile;
    }
```

Comment: I found documents about batch requests, can it help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp#batches-with-dependent-requests

Comment: Thanks for the link but yea I have read that previously. There is a line in their code that states POST request should be handled differently and they add content to the get request manually. However, the example was not useful in my scenario as the sdk already includes the content in the functions so I wasnt sure how to adapt my code to this.